# Project Reactor - subscribe on parallel scheduler doesn't work

Tags: kotlin, project-reactor, reactive-streams

I'm looking at examples and reading documentation and I've found some problems while trying to subscribe on Flux in a parallel manner.

I have a 3 functions, as below.

```
private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("main")
private val sequence = Flux.just(1, 2)

fun a() {
    sequence.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).subscribe { log.info("*** {}", it) }
    sequence.subscribe { log.info(">>> {}", it) }
}

fun b() {
    sequence.subscribe { log.info(">>> {}", it) }
}

fun c() {
    sequence.subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).subscribe { log.info("*** {}", it) }
}
```

Now, when I run each method separately I have a proper output from functions `a()` and `b()`, but output from `c()` is empty. Is that to be expected, is it by design? If so, why is that happening?

Comment: Of course, you're using `just` directly without using `defer`

Comment: I'm just following core reference docs and early examples while trying to experiment a little bit. Since you clearly know explanation, please, make it into an answer. A `defer` doesn't tell me much at this point.

Comment: Actually I'm basing this on RxJava, but if you return `Flux.just` from a `Flux.defer`, you'll be able to schedule it on a different thread, while `just` runs immediately so its execution can't be moved to different thread. I was looking for a construct like `Observable.fromCallable` but it doesn't seem to exist, so I think `Flux.defer { Flux.just` would work.

Comment: Have you had the chance to try it?

Comment: I wrapped as suggested `Flux.defer { Flux.just(1, 2) }`. Method `c()` still doesn't produce output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Flux.just(...)` captures value(s) and thus is optimized to execute immediately in the subscribing `Thread`.

When you use `subscribeOn`, you change that subscribing `Thread` from `main` to something else, making the `just` truly asynchronous.

In `a()`, without a `subscribeOn` that second `just` would block the main thread just enough that the test doesn't finish before the asynchronous alternative completes.

In `c()`, there is no such blocking of the `main` thread. As a consequence, the test terminates before the asynchronous `just` has had time to emit anything, and that is why you see no output.

To make that more visible, add a `Thread.sleep(10)` and you'll see some output.